# How to get user video list through Youtube API in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api

How can i get playlist feed in asp.net through Youtube APT.
I got Totalresult =o when i tried to fetch data.
Please see the image below:

[image]

Please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: follow this link, in this sample show how you can use Google PAI
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613903/youtube-api-v3-get-list-of-users-videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

        //Iterate through each video entry
        foreach (Video videoEntry in videoFeed.Entries)
        {

.
.
.
```

[Dynamically Output A List of YouTube Videos In ASP.NET](http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2009/05/26/Dynamically-Output-A-List-of-YouTube-Videos-In-ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: what will be the value of feedUrl variable