# Youtube video list without account (with the new API v3)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I saw the change of youtube api from v2 to v3 and my app broke.
I only need to get the last video from a channel and before, with the v2 it was easy and straight forward, you did not need any account login, but now things changed.
My old api v2 call was like this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XYZ/uploads?alt=json&max-results=1

how can I get the same result with the v3 without any app api key, login etc...?

Thanks

Comment: I was looking For the same thing and [this link][1] Helped me lot.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613903/youtube-api-v3-get-list-of-users-videos

Comment: You cant do it with out an API key, you are going to have to register your application and get a key.

Comment: @chiragchavda.ks thanks! I began to be lost in the ocean of informations :)

Comment: @DaImTo yeah, I figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use the API. Getting a key is free and easy. However if you REALLY don't want to, you could try the complicated route of parsing the webpage itself for the data using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Example:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/[CHANNEL_ID]';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
```

Which you can then parse with [DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php).

Comment: yeah I thought to use regex or similar