# Getting the last N videos uploaded and check if they're assigned to any playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building a tool to help creators improve their Channel's activity/revenue/visibility/whatever.

One of the checks is about the videos being or not into a playlist.

For what I can see I can get the list of most recent video uploaded with the [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) then I thought to just call the [playlistItem.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/l) to verify if there is a match passing the videoId but instead I see that I need to pass a playlistId too at least. So this is not viable.

The only way seems to get all the playlist of the channel (playlist.list) and then get the last *N* items of every Playlist (with playlistItems.list) and then run some verification of these results locally.

Is this really the best possible solution?

Comment: possible Duplicate of [Youtube api v3 Get list of user's videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613903/youtube-api-v3-get-list-of-users-videos)

Comment: That question ask how to get video of a user. This question ask which is the best way to have the playlist name in which a video is, if applicable. Or at least if it's in a playlist at all.