# Get list of youtube channels a user have

Tags: java, spring, youtube-api

I am trying to get a list of channel id a user have made using YouTube Data API (V3). How do I do this? I have user access token obtained after authorisation.

I want to fetch subscriber count for each channel which I have already done by passing one of the ID I know for a channel but that is for testing purposes.

I am using `RestTemplate` from `org.springframework.web.client` to make the request.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

//what parameters to set?

URIBuilder uriBuilder = URIBuilder.fromUri("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels");
```

I tried implementing a solution, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616491/3913366) SO answer but wasn't even able to make a good request.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: As shown in the tag, I am using Java Spring framework. Is that the right tag I am using?

Comment: "wasn't even able to make a good request." i didnt get this part

Comment: I meant that the parameters Is set and made the request, I got a 400 error (Bad Request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have the right approach, using `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels`. If you just want to get channel IDs for the authenticated user, you can use the parameters `part=id` and `mine=true`.

To use the access token, you can follow one of the approaches [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API) - either include `Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN` in the HTTP request header, or as another query parameter `access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Example request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?
    part=id&
    mine=true&
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Example response, with channel IDs in the `items/id` field:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": ETAG,
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": ETAG,
   "id": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
  }
 ]
}
```

I don't have much guidance on how to make these requests using the Spring framework - if you're still having trouble, I recommend verifying that they work outside of Spring. You can find more info on the [channels#list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) page, and to test generating and using OAuth access tokens try the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving an [**Error 400**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.CommonRequestError):

> **BAD REQUEST**
>
> - **incompatibleParameters** - The request specifies two or more parameters that cannot be used in the same request.
> - **invalidFilters** - The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.
> - **invalidPageToken** - The request specifies an invalid page token.
> - *8missingRequiredParameter** - The request is missing a required parameter.
> - **unexpectedParameter** - The request specifies an unexpected parameter.

Check the Bad Request error description you are receiving to compare and change it with the sample codes and [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) guide to follow the correct format.

Try using [**Java Code Samples**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java) to familiarize yourself with Youtube Data API.

Sources:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples

https://youtu.be/HTr778JctJE?list=PLhBgTdAWkxeD0Kpo-Qtzv1Gc7UhPRrPgn