# Is it possible to get all videos of YouTube using its API?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to fetch all videos of YouTube. Not from any particular channel but *all existing* videos from YouTube. 
How to use the API to grab all?

Comment: All videos? You should use some conditions right? like all videos with the tag x or something

Comment: No I mean to get all videos availabe on youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr. Rebot's suggestion could be modified to:

1. Find a random video with the search.list function.
2. Get the channel ID from the JSON response:

   ```
   "kind": "youtube#video",
       "videoId": "nSDgHBxUbVQ"
      },
      "snippet": {
       "publishedAt": "2015-05-10T00:40:11.000Z",
       "channelId": "UC0C-w0YjGpqDXGB8IHb662A",
       "title": "Ed Sheeran - Photograph (Official Music Video)",
   ```

   With the channel ID, gather all uploads from that channel: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616491/7922428
3. Fetch another random channel, compare to previous channel IDs to make sure it's not a duplicate, repeat process.

Very ambitious project. One report in 2015 said 1.2 billion videos were online. One search.list request uses 100 units of a daily 1 million allowed (unless you pay for more). <strike>So you could theoretically process 10,000 videos per day. So in 120k days (328 years) you could have all the videos.</strike> Max 50 results per call would allow you to get .5 million videos per day.. a mere 6.5 years.

Comment: Thanks for the math! Emphasis on *"**one** report in 2015"*

Comment: Not to mention the reported 300k new videos uploaded daily
(https://www.quora.com/How-many-videos-are-uploaded-on-YouTube-every-day).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`search.list`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method and leave the `q` parameter blank to get random videos. But I agree with @Ashkar, use `q` parameter to get specific list of videos.

[image]

You can always try the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?type=video&maxResults=25&part=snippet) to test the **`search.list`** method.

Hope this helps.