# Getting all of the video IDs from a YouTube channel

Tags: node.js, youtube

I'm trying to download all of the videos from a YouTube channel. My original idea was using the YouTube API to get the "uploads" playlist ID (which contains all of the channel's videos), get the video IDs from it [(explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616491/10870820) and then download each video with ytdl.

But, I found the module [ytpl](https://github.com/TimeForANinja/node-ytpl), with which I can get all of the video IDs from a playlist, without using the YouTube API. I find it kind of unnecessary to have an API key just to make one request (also, quota), so: is there any way to get every video ID from a user ID (or just the "uploads" playlist ID) with ytdl or another module?

For example, if I pass this channel ID: `"UCuAXFkgsw1L7xaCfnd5JJOw"`[•](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuAXFkgsw1L7xaCfnd5JJOw) it'd give me **A.** an array of video IDs (`[dQw4w9WgXcQ, ...]`[•](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)) or **B.** its "uploads" playlist ID (`"UUuAXFkgsw1L7xaCfnd5JJOw"`[•](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUuAXFkgsw1L7xaCfnd5JJOw)).

Here is my original plan:

```js
var baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3"
var apiURL1 = `${baseURL}/channels?part=id&id=${channelId}&key=${key}`

request(apiURL1, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    const uploads = res.body.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads
    var apiURL2 = `${baseURL}/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${uploads}&maxResults=50&key=${key}`

    request(apiURL2, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        // cycle through pages and get IDs, too lazy to do it but you get the point :P
        // then download them with ytdl
    }
})
```

And here is my "goal:"

```js
var uploads = whatever.getPlaylists(channelId).uploads.id // get playlist called "uploads"
ytpl(uploads) // get videos
    .then((err, playlist) => {
        // download each video with ytdl
    })
```

Or:

```js
var videos = whatever.getAllVideos(channelId)
for (v of videos)
    // download with ytdl
```

**Also, I need to get all of the IDs, because in most cases my script will only need to download some videos, not all of them. So a solution like passing ytdl the channel/playlist URL to download all of them won't work.**

Comment: why not use the youtube-dl inbuilt function to load playlist? You could also only load the playlist-info https://superuser.com/questions/1341684/youtube-dl-how-download-only-the-playlist-not-the-files-therein

Comment: Thank you, I still need to get the playlist from the channel though :/