# Optimise YouTube data API calls

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API to fetch a list of videos for some of my favourite channels. Functionally, it's all working great but I am hitting the daily quota now that the list of channels I am interested in has grown.

I currently do this (pseudo code):

```
foreach( channelId in myListOfChannelIds){

  YouTubeService.Search.List("snippet")
    .ChannelId = channelId
    .Type = "video"
    .MaxResults = 10
    .Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date

  searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

  foreach( item in searchListResponse.Items ) {

    <process the item>
  }
}
```

This is fine; I get the most recent 10 videos for each of my channels.

What I think I would like to do is:

- For each Channel, establish the date of the last video
- For every channel that has a recent video in the past 'n' days, fetch the most recent 10 videos (as per the code above)

I can't see anything on the API for finding the last published date for a channel and the channel list doesn't appear to have summary metadata exposed.

Does anyone have any pointers in case I have missed something or can suggest a better way to achieve my objective? it seems the channel list is an expensive (in units) operation.

Thanks in advance

(I'm using C#)

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616491/7123660

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it doesn't have a time element that indicates the last post date/time for a channel

Comment: The [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint by default lists videos from the most recent one to the oldest one. If you really look for a date (even if [optimizing performance](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#performance) isn't enough) then you can still use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=snippet` which will give you a `publishedAt` field.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `channel_id`, you can save quota by follow these steps:

1. Change the second letter of the channel_id to "**`U`**".

Example:

> Channel_id: **`UCYzHwra_yDr-QGFiopiOPnw`**, change it to: **`UUYzHwra_yDr-QGFiopiOPnw`**

The changed **`channel_id`** is the **"uploads" playlist** of the given channel.

2. Then, use this endpoint instead:

> `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=<UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID>`

Example:

> `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=UUYzHwra_yDr-QGFiopiOPnw`

You will see there the recent 15 videos uploaded by that channel and each entry has the info you need.